# onAuthStateChanged Firebase function

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, react-native-firebase

I have created an app in react native and used firebase in this.
I created screens and imported them in the screens in App.js for `createStackNavigator` so that I can navigate to another screen using this.

I am facing a problem in this. when I make changes to the other screen `firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged` fire every time.
How can I stop that `firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged` will fire on the screen I am working on? Do you have any resolution for this or is there any other way to check that the user is login or not in firebase instead of `firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged`.

Comment: It sounds like your transitions are loading a new page, in which case the auth state listener will indeed fire for the new screen. But instead of describing your code, edit your question to include the [minimal-but-complete code with which we can reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: It is not 100% clear what is your exact goal, and if you really need a listener, but note that you could also "get the currently signed-in user by using the [currentUser](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#current-user) property" ... "If a user isn't signed in, `currentUser´ is null". Of course it will then be your responsability to detect when the user is signed in (which is done automatically with `onAuthStateChanged`)